# How to add and use Local custom font in a Laravel+ TailwindCss+ Vuejs project?

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, font-face, tailwind-css

As the title suggests, I'm trying to add and use my own custom fonts in my project that I'm building using Laravel 8 as backend , Vuejs 3 as frontend and tailwindCSS 2 as my CSS framework.

I've tried many ways but the **only time I got my font displayed** was when I used a `<style>` tag in my **.blade.php** with normal css (**@font-face**) & **ids** inside of it.
I also tried *"@layer base"* way (as said in the official docs) but it didn't work

*\resources\css\app.css*

```
@layer base {
        @font-face {
        font-family: IRANSans;
        font-weight: 900;
        src:url(/fonts/IRANSansWeb_Black.woff2) format("woff2"), 
        url(/fonts/IRANSansWeb_Black.woff) format("woff"),
         url(/fonts/IRANSansWeb_Black.ttf) format("truetype");
      }
      
      @font-face {
        font-family: PlatNomor;
        font-weight: 900;
        src:url(/fonts/PlatNomor.woff2) format("woff2"), 
        url(/fonts/PlatNomor.woff) format("woff"),
         url(/fonts/PlatNomor.ttf) format("truetype");
      }  
}
```

*I've tried many urls but none of them worked

\tailwind.config.js

```
theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'irsans': ['IRANSans'],
      'pln': ['PlatNomor']
    },
```

and the class names I used inside of Vuejs components : `font-irsans` & `font-pln`

So my questions are:

1. Where should I put my font files?
2. How do I let tailwind know where my font files are in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your font files need to be within a directory called font at the public root of your project, i.e: `yourproject.com/font/` as that is what you specified in your font-face declaration.
2. You don't need to, Tailwind does not care where your font files are, or even if they exist, Tailwind simply creates a class that references your font-family by the name you gave, e.g: `.font-irsans`.

Also, there's no point in specifying the truetype version, no browser will use that. .woff and .woff2 are enough to cover all recent browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. Can you tell me where I can learn more about Laravel's file systems and other topics related to these type of issues ?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've never used Laravel.